# How to get value from object based on propertyName in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can do this in javascript

```
const chipColors = {
  delivered: "success",
  pending: "warning",
  canceled: "danger"
}

<Chip
   color={chipColors[row.order_status]} <-- Typescript will throw error on this line
   text={row.order_status}
/>
```

But Typescript is giving me error message `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`

Comment: Can you show us the type of the `row` variable? And the remainder of the error message, looks like it was cut off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`row.order_status` is typed as a string. While `chipColors` only accepts a key that is of the type `delivered | pending | canceled`. So, either you type `row.order_status` differently, or, you can do a type guard, to check if order status is a `chipColors` key, like so:

```
const chipColors = {
  delivered: "success",
  pending: "warning",
  canceled: "danger",
};

const key = "delivered";

function isChipColor(key: string): key is keyof typeof chipColors {
  return Object.keys(chipColors).includes(key);
}

if (!isChipColor(key)) {
  return null
}
return <Chip ... />
```